# How to know if an actor is touched in libgdx?

Tags: android, sprites, libgdx, touch

I am using "Gdx.input.isTouched()" in the render method of my Screen method, to know where is touched, but when the touch is dragged in the screen, it also activates the events i want only when an actor is touched.

Is there any listener to know when an Actor is touched, but the event is not the dragged one, im doing it with sprites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `TouchUp` and `TouchDown` method if I'm not mistaken. You need to keep track of state.

I handle this in my projects by creating a custom `MyAwesomeSprite` class; on `TouchDown`, I just set `_isTouched=true`, and on `TouchUp`, I set `_isTouched = false`. This allows me to detect dragging (touch-down triggered when `_isTouched` is already true), so I can easily distinguish between these two cases.

Comment: The touchDown and touchMethod is for the Screen(Stage) right?

Comment: Not sure. I get mine from the `Game` class, which implements `ApplicationListener` and `InputProcessor`

Answer (score 2):

Add a Listener to the actor like so. Note you need an InputMultiplexer so your Stage and Screen can both handle touches. Add the Stage first so it gets clicks first, then in the Listener call event.handle() and return true otherwise the touch will bubble through and be picked up by your Screen too.

```
actor.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                doSomething(x,y,pointer);
                event.handle();//the Stage will stop trying to handle this event
                return true; //the inputmultiplexer will stop trying to handle this touch
            }
        });
```

Some actors will require

```
Actor.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
```